# static const references to temporaries

Tags: c++

I have a templated class that is dependent on two template parameters to calculate its values but only one for construction.  I would like to relieve the dependency on the second over its lifetime.  I am looking at doing this by using a templated static function to calculate the values and then create an instance.  All of the members inside this class are const POD types and there will be a good many of this class being created at application start up.

```
template < class member >
class FOO {
public:
 FOO() : a(7) {};

 template < class scope >
 static FOO CreateFOO()
 {
  return FOO();
 };

private:
 const int a;
};

template < class member, class scope >
const FOO< member >* function()
{
 static const FOO< member >& temp = FOO< member >::CreateFOO< scope >();

 return &temp;
}

int main() {

 const FOO<int>* b = function< int, int >();

 return 0;
}
```

I contemplated move semantics but because I am simply containing const POD types there really isn't any swapping and moving simply copying and destroying.  Is the above reasonable/valid?  Everything I have read suggests it is ok!  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't see any rationale for using `static const Type&` instead of `static const Type`. What do you think that it gains you?

Comment: I can bind to an rvalue?  without copying?

Comment: A compiler should optimize away the copying if you return the new object by value, but indeed there's no guarantee for that. I wish it was predictable when the copying occurs and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be okay.  Since the reference `temp` is bound to the temporary object, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of `temp`, which extends past the end of `main()`.

But I don't see any real reason to use a reference there.  Why not just:

```
{
    static const FOO<member> foo = FOO<member>::CreateFOO<scope>();
    return &foo;
}
```

Your compiler can probably optimize away the copy constructor.  And if not, you say it's all POD members, so no big deal.

Either way, you might worry about the [static deinitialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ctors.html#faq-10.16).  Or maybe you're sure they'll never be used from destructors.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is a contrived example. Still there is no reason given for the existence of `static FOO CreateFOO()`, which in this case does nothing other than default constructing the object. If you simply created a template constructor:

```
template < class member >
class FOO {
public:
template < class scope > FOO(scope);
```

then you would have a standard form for your singleton:

```
template < class member, class scope >
const FOO< member >& function(scope your_scope)
{
 static FOO<member> temp(your_scope);
 return temp;
}
```

Comment: I am not looking to create a Singleton, FOO<member> is created in the context of scope but the dependency on scope is only for the duration of construction.  I can have many FOO<int>s all with different const values.  The static initializer functions are in scope but FOO< member > is accessed outside of scope.  There can also be many FOO<int>s in scope.  I hope this makes sense :/